Fill in matrices for matrix bit flipping as quickly as possible
Consider an n by n binary matrix.  If it has rank r <= n, then we want to compute the largest number bits flips necessary to reduce its rank to a specific value. All computations should be done over \$\mathbb{F}_2\$ (that is mod 2).
If r = n, then the answer is 1 to change it to n-1. If r = 1, it can need \$n^2\$ bit flips  to change the rank to zero by considering the all ones matrix.
For any given matrix, there is a minimum number of bit flips needed to reduce its rank to a specific value. The task is to compute the maximum of these minima taken over all n by n binary matrices as a function of n, the rank r of the matrix and the rank that it will be changed to.
Task
For each n starting at 2, complete the \$n+1\$ by \$n+1\$ matrix giving the optimal value (that is maximum of the minima) to go from each rank less than or equal to n to each rank less than or equal to n. The smallest possible rank is 0.
Worked example
Let us work through a complete example for n = 2. There are 16 different 2 by 2 binary matrices.  The only rank 0 matrix is:
0 0
0 0

The rank 1 matrices are:
0 0
0 1

0 0
1 0

0 0
1 1

0 1
0 0

0 1
0 1

1 0
0 0

1 0
1 0

1 1
0 0

1 1
1 1

The rank 2 matrices are:
0 1
1 0

0 1
1 1

1 0
0 1

1 0
1 1

1 1
0 1

1 1
1 0

To compute the output matrix for n = 2 let us start with the only rank 0 matrix. There is no rank smaller than 0 and it costs zero flips to keep the rank the same.
Now let us look at the matrices with rank 1.  The first one above has only one 1 so the minimum number of flips for that matrix is 1 to get to rank 0. But we need to find the maximum over the minima over all rank 1 matrices. We see at the end of the list there is a matrix of all ones. That will take us 4 flips to get to rank 0 so that is our answer for going from rank 1 to rank 0.  Rank 1 to itself of course needs zero flips.
Now let us look at the matrices with rank 2.  First let us consider going from rank 2 to rank 1.  We can see that there is always one bit we can flip to do that so that is going to be our output. To go from rank 2 to rank 0 we can see that the maximum number of ones is 3 so that is going to be our output.
All in, the full output for n = 2 is therefore going to be:
n = 2:

0  
4 0 
3 1 0 

Each row corresponds to the rank of the matrix to start with and the column corresponds to the rank we are going to.  We don't fill in the top right as this corresponds to increasing the rank.
Sample outputs
Here are the outputs for n = 2,3,4,5.
n = 2:

0  
4 0 
3 1 0 

n = 3:

0   
9 0  
8 3 0 
7 3 1 0 

n = 4:

0    
16 0 
15 6 0 
14 6 3 0 
13 6 3 1 0 

n = 5

0
25 0
24 9 0 
23 9 4 0 
22 9 6 3 0
21 10 5 3 1 0

n=5 matrix completed thanks to @ovs
n = 6:

0
36 0
35 12 0
34 14 8 0
33 14 9 4 0
32 14 8 6 3 0
31 14 8 5 3 1 0

n=6 thanks to @AndersKaseorg
Score
The score for your code is the number of correct non-zero matrix values it outputs on my Linux PC (16GB, 4 cores, 8 threads) in one minute.  Your code must start at n=2 and finish all the values for a matrix size before it starts the next size up.
Results

45 by Anders Kaseorg in Rust
34 by ovs in C
34 by jdt in C++ (port of ovs's)


I don't understand about the rank-1 matrix of all ones -- wouldn't a single bit flip change its rank?

I still find the text confusing. First we're talking about changing the rank, then reducing the rank, then going to a rank of a specific value.

@xnor You are right. I have fixed it now I hope

I think the 5x5 matrix [[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,1]] needs 6 bits flipped to go from rank 4 to rank 2, which contradicts the 4 in the fifth row of sample output for n=5

@ovs Thank you! I had made an assumption which wasn’t true. I have put ? where I am not sure of the answer.

Rust, score ≈ 44
The main idea here is to take advantage of symmetry by avoiding redundant processing of matrices obtained by rearranging the rows of other processed matrices.
This uses a different output format because for each \$n\$ it computes the nontrivial values in ascending order by value rather than positionally (which is allowed by the rules):
2 1 0: 4
2 2 0: 3
2 2 1: 1
…

On my system, this completes \$n ≤ 5\$ in 0.2 seconds, prints 10 additional entries from \$n = 6\$ within the 1 minute time limit, and completes \$n ≤ 6\$ in 4 minutes. The complete values for \$n = 6\$, converted back to the sample output format, are
n = 6:

0
36 0
35 12 0
34 14 8 0
33 14 9 4 0
32 14 8 6 3 0
31 14 8 5 3 1 0

Build with cargo build --release and run with target/release/rank.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "rank"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rayon = "1.10.0"

src/main.rs
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::cmp::Reverse;

type Matrix = u64;
type Row = u8;
const SIZE: usize = 8;
const COLUMN_MASK: Matrix = Matrix::MAX / !(!0 << SIZE);

fn matrix_rows(matrix: Matrix) -> [Row; SIZE] {
    matrix.to_le_bytes()
}

fn rows_matrix(rows: [Row; SIZE]) -> Matrix {
    Matrix::from_le_bytes(rows)
}

fn make_coeffs(n: usize) -> (Vec<usize>, usize) {
    let mut coeffs = vec![0; n << n];
    for row in (0..!(!0 << n)).rev() {
        coeffs[(n - 1) << n | row] = !(!0 << n) - row;
        for i in (0..n - 1).rev() {
            coeffs[i << n | row] = coeffs[(i + 1) << n | row] + coeffs[i << n | (row + 1)];
        }
    }
    let num_matrices = (0..n).map(|i| coeffs[i << n as usize]).sum::<usize>() + 1;
    (coeffs, num_matrices)
}

fn encode(n: usize, coeffs: &[usize], matrix: Matrix) -> usize {
    let mut rows = matrix_rows(matrix);
    rows[0..n].sort();
    rows[0..n]
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, &row)| coeffs[i << n | row as usize])
        .sum()
}

fn decode(n: usize, coeffs: &[usize], mut matrix_code: usize) -> Matrix {
    let mut rows = [0; SIZE];
    for i in 0..n {
        let row = coeffs[i << n..(i + 1 << n) - 1]
            .binary_search_by_key(&Reverse(&matrix_code), Reverse)
            .unwrap_or_else(|coeff| coeff);
        rows[i] = row as Row;
        matrix_code -= coeffs[i << n | row];
    }
    return rows_matrix(rows);
}

fn main() {
    for n in 2..=6 {
        for i in 1..=n {
            // Trivial: matrix of all 1s except i - 1 diagonal 0s
            println!("{n} {i} 0: {}", n * n - i + 1);
        }

        let (coeffs, num_matrices) = make_coeffs(n);

        let mut ranks = vec![0u8; num_matrices];
        let mut split = num_matrices - 1;
        for i in (0..n).rev() {
            let new_split = split - coeffs[i << n];
            let (new_ranks, old_ranks) = ranks.split_at_mut(split);
            new_ranks[new_split..]
                .par_iter_mut()
                .zip(new_split..split)
                .for_each(|(square_rank, matrix_code)| {
                    let matrix = decode(n, &coeffs, matrix_code);
                    let row = matrix >> (SIZE * (n - 1));
                    let column = (matrix >> row.trailing_zeros()) & COLUMN_MASK;
                    *square_rank =
                        old_ranks[encode(n, &coeffs, matrix ^ (column * row)) - split] + 1;
                });
            split = new_split;
        }

        let mut flood: Vec<Row> = ranks
            .iter()
            .map(|&rank| if rank == n as u8 { 0 } else { 1 << rank })
            .collect();

        let mut reached = [0; SIZE + 1];
        let mut flips = 0;
        while {
            let mut new_reached = [!0; SIZE + 1];
            for (&b, &rank) in flood.iter().zip(&ranks) {
                new_reached[rank as usize] &= b;
            }
            let mut unfinished = false;
            for i in 0..=n {
                for j in 1..i {
                    if (new_reached[i] >> j) & 1 == 0 {
                        unfinished = true;
                    } else if (reached[i] >> j) & 1 == 0 {
                        println!("{n} {i} {j}: {flips}");
                    }
                }
                reached[i] = new_reached[i];
            }
            unfinished
        } {
            flood = flood
                .par_iter()
                .copied()
                .enumerate()
                .map(|(matrix_code, mut b)| {
                    let matrix = decode(n, &coeffs, matrix_code);
                    for i in 0..n {
                        for j in 0..n {
                            b |= flood[encode(n, &coeffs, matrix ^ (1 << (SIZE * i + j)))];
                        }
                    }
                    b
                })
                .collect();
            flips += 1;
        }
    }
}


The first column derives from all the ones matrices with r 0s down the diagonal. These have rank r and have $n^2 - r + 1$ ones.  What does the second almost constant column correspond to?

The $(n,2,1)$ values 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 17, 24, 29, 36, 43, 54, 61, 70, 81, 96, 105, 117, 131, 150, … are pretty easy to compute; they seem to be maximized by block matrices $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&1\1&0&1\1&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ with row and column widths $\left(\frac n4+O(1),\frac n4+O(1),\frac n2+O(1)\right)$, and grow like $\frac38n^2+O(n)$.

Your code take only 2min25 seconds for me to complete n=6! I am particularly impressed by the low memory usage. For n = 7 it does fail with a memory allocation error after outputting all the first column.

C++ (clang)
Direct port of ovs's answer with some parallelization thrown in.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

void flips(int n) {
    int N = 1 << (n * n);
    std::vector<char> ranks(N), X(N), Y(N);

    // Compute ranks of all 2^(n*n) matrices
    ranks[0] = 0;
    int mask = (N - 1) / ((1 << n) - 1);
    for (int x = 1; x < N; ++x) {
        int matrix = x;
        int pivot = matrix % (1 << n);
        int lsb = pivot & -pivot;
        matrix >>= n;
        ranks[x] = lsb ? ranks[matrix ^ (matrix / lsb & mask) * pivot] + 1 : ranks[matrix];
    }

    // Result table
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> results(n + 1, std::vector<int>(n + 1, 0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) results[i][0] = n * n - i + 1; // First column

    // For each j, spread js until j is the maximum value.
    // The maximum number of flips needed for rank i -> j is equivalent
    // to the number of iterations where `X` contained i.
    for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
        std::memcpy(Y.data(), ranks.data(), N);
        int w;
        do {
            w = 0;
            std::memcpy(X.data(), Y.data(), N);

            #pragma omp parallel for
            for (int x = 0; x < N; ++x) {
                if (X[x] == j) {
                    for (int b = 1; b < N; b *= 2) Y[x ^ b] = j;
                } else if (X[x] > j) {
                    w |= 1 << X[x];
                }
            }
            for (int i = j + 1; i <= n; ++i) results[i][j] += (w >> i) & 1;
        } while (w);
    }

    // Print results
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            std::cout << results[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int n = 2; n <= 5; ++n) {
        std::cout << "n=" << n << '\n';
        flips(n);
    }
    return 0;
}


Try it online!

How high can you get?

Still only 5. You'll need a totally different approach to get n = 6 in a minute.

The problem seems to be memory. There is no need to get all of n=6 as you still get scoring points for any part of it you can compute.

C (clang -O2)
Locally this takes 15 seconds for n=5. For computing further results, some of the ints have to be changed to long, but it won't be to close to completing n=6 within a minute.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void flips(int n) {
  int N = 1 << n*n;
  char *ranks = malloc(sizeof *ranks * N),
       *X = malloc(sizeof *X * N),
       *Y = malloc(sizeof *Y * N);

  // compute ranks of all 2^(n*n) matrices
  ranks[0] = 0;
  int mask = (N - 1) / ((1<<n) - 1);
  for (int x=1; x<N; x++) {
    int matrix = x,
        pivot = matrix%(1<<n),
        lsb = pivot&-pivot;
    matrix >>= n;
    ranks[x] = lsb ? ranks[matrix ^ (matrix/lsb & mask) * pivot]+1 : ranks[matrix];
  }

  // result table
  int results[n+1][n+1];
  memset(results, 0, sizeof results);
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) results[i][0] = n*n-i+1; // first column

  // for each j, spread js until j is the maximum value.
  // the maximum number of flips needed for rank i -> j is equivalent
  // to the number of iterations where `X` contained i.
  for (int j=1; j<n; j++) {
    memcpy(Y, ranks, N);
    int w;
    do {
      w=0, memcpy(X, Y, N);
      for(int x=0; x<N; x++) {
        if (X[x]==j)
          for (int b=1;b<N;b*=2) Y[x^b] = j;
        else if (X[x]>j)
          w|=1<<X[x];
      }
      for(int i=j+1;i<=n;i++) results[i][j] += w>>i&1;
    } while (w);
  }

  // print results
  for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
      printf("%d ", results[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  free(ranks), free(X), free(Y);
}

int main() {
  for(int n=2;n<=5;n++)
    printf("n=%d\n", n),
    flips(n);
  return 0;
}

Try it online!

15 seconds is impressive. Will your code output any of the answers for n=6 in the time do you think?

@Simd Currently the entire output is printed after computation, adjusting that will make it a bit more complex. But even then, you'll need ~200GB (3*2^(6*6) bytes) of RAM for n=6

That is more than I have!

Python
Python port of @Anders Kaseorg's Rust answer.
import sys
from typing import List, Tuple

SIZE = 8
COLUMN_MASK = 0x0101010101010101

def matrix_rows(matrix: int) -> List[int]:
    """Convert a 64-bit integer matrix to a list of 8 byte rows (little endian)."""
    return list(matrix.to_bytes(SIZE, 'little'))

def rows_matrix(rows: List[int]) -> int:
    """Convert a list of 8 byte rows back to a 64-bit integer matrix (little endian)."""
    return int.from_bytes(bytes(rows), 'little')

def trailing_zeros(x: int, size: int = SIZE) -> int:
    """Calculate the number of trailing zero bits in an integer."""
    if x == 0:
        return size
    return (x & -x).bit_length() - 1

def binary_search_desc(lst: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    """
    Perform a binary search on a descending sorted list.
    Returns the first index where lst[index] <= target.
    If no such index exists, returns len(lst).
    """
    low, high = 0, len(lst)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if lst[mid] > target:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid
    return low

def make_coeffs(n: int) -> Tuple[List[int], int]:
    """
    Generate coefficient table and number of unique matrices for a given size n.
    """
    coeffs = [0] * (n << n)  # Equivalent to n * (2^n)
    for row in reversed(range(1 << n)):
        coeffs[(n - 1) << n | row] = (1 << n) - 1 - row
        for i in reversed(range(n - 1)):
            if row + 1 < (1 << n):
                coeffs[i << n | row] = coeffs[(i + 1) << n | row] + coeffs[i << n | (row + 1)]
            else:
                coeffs[i << n | row] = coeffs[(i + 1) << n | row]
    num_matrices = sum(coeffs[i << n] for i in range(n)) + 1
    return coeffs, num_matrices

def encode(n: int, coeffs: List[int], matrix: int) -> int:
    """
    Encode a matrix into a unique integer code based on sorted rows and coefficients.
    """
    rows = matrix_rows(matrix)[:n]
    sorted_rows = sorted(rows)
    return sum(coeffs[(i << n) | row] for i, row in enumerate(sorted_rows))

def decode(n: int, coeffs: List[int], matrix_code: int) -> int:
    """
    Decode an integer code back into the original matrix.
    """
    rows = [0] * SIZE
    for i in range(n):
        search_range = coeffs[i << n : (i + 1) << n]
        row = binary_search_desc(search_range, matrix_code)
        rows[i] = row
        if (i << n | row) >= len(coeffs):
            print(f"Error: Index out of bounds during decode. i={i}, row={row}")
            sys.exit(1)
        matrix_code -= coeffs[(i << n) | row]
    return rows_matrix(rows)

def main():
    for n in range(2, 7):
        # Print trivial matrices information
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            print(f"{n} {i} 0: {n * n - i + 1}")

        coeffs, num_matrices = make_coeffs(n)
        ranks = [0] * num_matrices
        split = num_matrices - 1

        # Assign ranks based on coefficients
        for i in reversed(range(n)):
            new_split = split - coeffs[i << n]
            new_ranks = ranks[:split].copy()
            old_ranks = ranks[split:]
            for k, matrix_code in enumerate(range(new_split, split)):
                matrix = decode(n, coeffs, matrix_code)
                row = (matrix >> (SIZE * (n - 1))) & 0xFF
                tz = trailing_zeros(row, SIZE)
                column = (matrix >> tz) & COLUMN_MASK
                new_matrix = matrix ^ (column * row)
                encoded = encode(n, coeffs, new_matrix)
                if encoded < split:
                    print(f"Error: Encoded value {encoded} is less than split {split}")
                    sys.exit(1)
                square_rank = old_ranks[encoded - split] + 1
                new_ranks[k + new_split] = square_rank
            ranks[:split] = new_ranks
            split = new_split

        # Initialize flood
        flood = [0 if rank == n else (1 << rank) for rank in ranks]
        reached = [0] * (SIZE + 1)
        flips = 0

        # Perform flood fill
        while True:
            new_reached = [~0] * (SIZE + 1)
            for b, rank in zip(flood, ranks):
                new_reached[rank] &= b
            unfinished = False
            for i in range(0, n + 1):
                for j in range(1, i):
                    if ((new_reached[i] >> j) & 1) == 0:
                        unfinished = True
                    elif ((reached[i] >> j) & 1) == 0:
                        print(f"{n} {i} {j}: {flips}")
            reached = new_reached
            if not unfinished:
                break

            # Update flood
            new_flood = []
            for matrix_code, b in enumerate(flood):
                matrix = decode(n, coeffs, matrix_code)
                for i_row in range(n):
                    for j_col in range(n):
                        bit = 1 << (SIZE * i_row + j_col)
                        flipped_matrix = matrix ^ bit
                        encode_code = encode(n, coeffs, flipped_matrix)
                        if encode_code >= len(flood):
                            print(f"Error: Encoded value {encode_code} out of bounds for flood")
                            sys.exit(1)
                        b |= flood[encode_code]
                new_flood.append(b)
            flood = new_flood
            flips += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Attempt This Online!
